# eliminate the enter key after pressing it in the keyup event of a textbox

Tags: .net, textbox

How to cancel a keypress event in a textbox after pressing the return key.

Comment: Duh, this is tagged .net, I deleted my irrelevant answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Handled property of KeyPressEventArgs handler parameter to true.

Example from msdn:

```
private void keypressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, you want it to ignore the enter key ?

You could add a keydown event and ignore the enter key there...

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```