# When the user presses "Enter" in a ToolStripTextBox (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, events, textbox

I have a ToolStripTextBox (the name of it is SearchBox) and I would like it when after the user types something and presses enter it takes them to a URL. I've got the URL part sorted out, but I need to know what goes after

```
Handles SearchBox.{what?}
```

I don't see any event in the intellisense popup for something when the user presses "enter."

So, in other words, how do I perform an action after the user presses enter?

```
    Private Sub ToolStripComboBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchBox.**?????**

    Dim SearchString As String
    SearchString = SearchBox.Text

    Dim URL As String
    URL = ("https://www.example.com/search.php?&q=" + SearchString)

    Process.Start(URL)
End Sub
```

Comment: OnEnter doesn't work... something about protected.

Answer (score 2):

Got it from:

[eliminate the enter key after pressing it in the keyup event of a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236675/eliminate-the-enter-key-after-pressing-it-in-the-keyup-event-of-a-textbox)

Not exact, but it helped.

```
    Public Sub SearchBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles SearchBox.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

        Dim SearchString As String
        SearchString = SearchBox.Text

        Dim URL As String
        URL = ("https://www.example.com/search.php?search=" + SearchString)

        Process.Start(URL)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should clean that up to only have this after the If statement:

Process.Start("https://www.example.com/search.php?search=" & SearchBox.Text.Trim)

Much cleaner. You may also want to validate that something was entered in the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the SearchBox_KeyUp or the SearchBox_KeyPress event.

Take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.keyup.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.keypress.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I can't figure out how to implement it though. Will try.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, pressing any key causes the URL to load!

```
    Public Sub SearchBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles SearchBox.KeyPress

        Dim messageBoxVB As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Enter", e.KeyChar)
        messageBoxVB.AppendLine()


        Dim SearchString As String
        SearchString = SearchBox.Text

        Dim URL As String
        URL = ("https://www.example.com/search.php?search=" + SearchString)

        Process.Start(URL)
    End Sub
End Class
```

How do I check for **enter**?